# Wrapping a string with $() and finding an element inside it

Tags: jquery

Given a string that is the html of a page, how can I find a specific element in it?

For example

```
var foo = "<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="subcontainer">
                <li>1</li>
                <li>2</li>
                <li>3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>";
```

How can I get `<ul class="subcontainer"><li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li></ul>`?

I tried wrapping the string using jQuery and finding the element via filter

```
var bar = $(foo).filter('.container ul.subcontainer');
```

How to solve this?

**UPDATE**

I am using jQuery 2.0.2

Comment: First, that string is illegal Javascript. Second, you don't have a `ul` with the class `foobar`. Third, you are looking  for the `find` method.

Comment: You should use `$.parseHTML` instead. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseHTML/

Comment: Fixed typo. Also formatted the javascript string in a way that is easily readable, but in the code it is compressed.

Comment: why don't you accept any answer?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var bar = $(foo).find('.subcontainer')
```

Comment: I got the object but calling `.html()` on it returns undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things, first Javascript needs `\` for multi line strings, and you also need to escape the inner `"` characters:

```
var foo = "<html>\
    <head>\
        <title>Test</title>\
    </head>\
    <body>\
        <div class=\"container\">\
            <ul class=\"subcontainer\">\
                <li>1</li>\
                <li>2</li>\
                <li>3</li>\
            </ul>\
        </div>\
    </body>\
</html>";
```

Then, use `find` instead of filter:

```
var obj = $(foo).find("ul.subcontainer");
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Ng5GT/

Comment: I got the object but calling `.html()` on it returns undefined.